# Advice about fallback font stacks for Proxima Nova and Adobe Garamond Pro

Tags: fonts, typography, web-fonts

Can anyone suggest a good stack of fallback fonts for Adobe Garamond Pro (serif) and Proxima Nova (sans-serif)?

The obvious choices are of course:

`"Garamond Pro","Hoefler Text","Times New Roman",Times,serif`

and

`"Proxima Nova",Arial,sans-serif`

Thank you,

Answer (score 11):

Constantia would be a better fallback than Times New Roman for Garamond, and Corbel would arguably be a better fallback than Arial for Proxima Nova.  They may also have Gill Sans installed with some software, plus Open Sans is not bad.

I'd put something like:

```
"Adobe Garamond Pro",Constantia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif

"Proxima Nova","Open Sans","Gill Sans MT","Gill Sans",Corbel,Arial,sans-serif
```

BUT you MUST remember to test your websites with each of these fallback fonts, because fonts often differ greatly in metrics.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're on the right track. I just code the page and try swapping fonts with something like FireBug to see what fits best.

Times is going to pose a problem for you. It won't match up with the metrics of Garamond (or Hoefler) at all. Try falling back to one of the newer MS fonts like Constantia.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning using a web font, self served or hosted.  If it is in the budget or technical capabilities of the client, a web-font will ensure the exact font is rendered on modern browsers.

There's a good chance you already have less-than-modern browser fallback styles, and that would be the only other variants you need to worry about, in which case a certain amount of compromise with layout is already on the table.

Answer (score -1):

Candara is the closest to Proxima Nova that I could find.